# Sorting a computed value based on the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a few computation code for the average based on the rows on my database. What I want is to get the sorted average on descending order when I echo it on my `<td>`. Can anybody share their thoughts? Thank you so much. Here's my piece of code.

```
foreach($records as $row){

    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $assignment[$i] = ((($row[$i]->assignment_scores/$row[$i]->assignment_perfect)*100)*0.1);
        $project[$i] = ((($row[$i]->project_scores/$row[$i]->project_perfect)*100)*0.3);
        $quarterexam[$i] = ((($row[$i]->quarterexam_scores/$row[$i]->quarterexam_perfect)*100)*0.4);
        $quiz[$i] = ((($row[$i]->quiz_scores/$row[$i]->quiz_perfect)*100)*0.15);
        $seatwork[$i] = ((($row[$i]->seatwork_scores/$row[$i]->seatwork_perfect)*100)*0.05);
        $average[$i] = $assignment[$i]+$project[$i]+$quarterexam[$i]+$quiz[$i]+$seatwork[$i];

        echo "<tr><td style='width: 200px;'>".$row[$i]->lname.', '.$row[$i]->fname.', '.$row[$i]->mname."</td><td style='padding-left:80px'>".$average[$i]."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the values to an array, then sort that array.

Comment: Where is the SQL code ? Its up to your database to do this job